# Android: Best way to share code between activities?

Tags: android

I'm using an include in several activities that contain a toolbar and a search text box and button.  I don't want to copy all of the same code to each, because that becomes a nightmare for edits and changes, etc.

What is the best way to get this done?

My initial thought is to create a new class, put the button code in there, and pass the activity to it, but I'm just not sure how to do this.

Thanks in advance for your help!
Mark

Comment: Don't pass Activities around.  Bad idea :)  Write a class that extends Activity and put your common code in that class.  Then use this class for all of your Activities which require this common code.  Just call `super.nameOfMethod()`

Answer (score 2):

Create a `BaseActivity` with the included `layout` for its `layout` with the functionality in that `BaseActivity`. Then `extends BaseActivity` in your other `Activities`.

Doing this you can override the functions in any of your `Activities` if you need more/different functionality from them. I do this so I can have a completely custom "Action Bar" in all of my `Activities`. My back button, overflow button, and another image  button functionality is all contained in the `BaseActivity`.

Comment: what about ListActivity, FragmentActivity, ActionBarActivity... ?

Comment: @Piotr I'm not sure what a `ListActivity` would do here but using `Fragments` is definitely a viable option. But this is how I did it at the time because I couldn't easily switch my app to using `Fragments`.

Comment: I meant that it's hard to share a activity-related code if you are using multiple Activity subclasses. I guess there's no any perfect solution for such case

Comment: @Piotr Ah, I see. Well, what I currently do is have a `BaseActivity` and a `BaseListActivity` to extend from. But using a `Fragment` is a good choice if you have that option

Answer (score 0):

The solution of codeMagic is elegant.
If you wanted to use this in more than one project, I'd recommend you to put this class (e.g. the "BaseActivity" in a library (mark this project as a library) and import this.