# Two activities sharing common functionality

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

I have two activities: `AddContact` and `EditContact`. They both share a lot of common instance variables and methods that act on that data.

What would be the best way to refactor this code so that there wouldn't be any duplicate code?

Can you recommend any specific design patterns to use? The most obvious of course would be inheritance, but since every activity in android already extends `Activity`, this is out of the question.

I already thought of making another class that extends `Activity`, then putting common variables and methods inside this class, and then initializing this class in both `AddContact` and `EditContact`. However, if this really is the best way to go, should I make all the methods and instance variables in this shared class static?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18859142/android-best-way-to-share-code-between-activities/18859239#18859239). You won't initialize the "base" `Activity`. You will `extends` your two `Activities` from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How is Inheritance out of the question?  You could have a base class that extends Activity, then have your two other classes extend that to inherit the shared functionality for example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
      //Common functionality and instance methods
}

public class AddContact extends MainActivity {
     //Has all of Main Activity's non private methods/variables
}

public class EditContact extends MainActivity {
    //Has all of MainActivity's non private methods/variables.
}
```

Also, if you don't want your MainActivity to be used directly, you could just make it abstract to ensure that the subclasses are used instead.  This gives you the perk of reducing redundancy by sharing methods/variables, and also allows you to extend this functionality to make it specific to each subclass, if needed.

The other option is to just use a Singleton to encapsulate common functionality.

Comment: Thank you, i'll look into both of the methods you suggested and see which one fits better for my needs :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on that exactly you want to share between two activities. But in my opinion, the best way would be to move common functionality into a [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html) and use it in both activities. If this functionality has visual elements, then it can be visible Fragment with layout. Otherwise it can be invisible fragment with pure logic in it.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend inheritance, creating a single class common code is really good for reusability however, take on count that each class extending from your base class will be allocating duplicated memory for things with the same purpose, google do not recommend it unless really necessary and the advantages you are getting out of it are really clear, you should take a look at the [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) design patterns, this seems like a good example of when to implement it, basically you will have 1 single instance that does the job among different components without having to allocate new objects every time, just reusing the one already created.

Hope it helps!

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Contact
{
   String name
   //implement the rest of contact's functionality
}



public class AddContact extends Activity
{
    // Create a new instance of Contact
}

public class EditContact extends Activity
{
   // Create a new instance of Contact
}
```

Only create static methods if it makes sense calling the method if an object has not been created